# How to manage complex sorting in SQL?

Tags: sql, sorting, date, columnsorting

I need to have date sorting  with the partial dates. I have a table with the following columns.

```
Day     Month   Year
--      ----    -----
NULL    03      1990
26      10      1856
03      07      Null
31      NULL    2018
NULL    NULL    NULL
```

I have a grid in which One of the column is Date where I am combining the above three columns and displays the dates.

Now I want sorting on this date column in the grid. The sort order of the dates should be like following :

```
[blank date]
22 [day]
March
April 12
May
July 29
August
September
September 14
October
1948
October 1948
October 1 1948
July 1976
1977
July 1977
July 23 1977
December 1981
December 29 1981
```

I have tried various ways to achieve this. But I am not able to get the desired result. Following are some of the ways I have applied.

I have tried sorting by creating the stored procedure in which I am creating the whole date by combining 3 columns and converting them in standard date formats and comparing the values. I have also tried by creating the computed property in the model and sorting them accordingly.

How can I do this in SQL?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do:

```
order by coalesce(year, '0000'), coalesce(month, '00'),  coalesce(day, '')
```

You can be more explicit, but this puts the `NULL` values before the other values in the column.

Note:  This uses the SQL standard operator for string concatenation.  Not all databases support this, so you might need to tweak the code for your database.